# Simultaneous reads of the same PyTorch torchvision.datasets object

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytorch, torchvision, dataloader

Consider the following piece of code to fetch a data set for training from `torchvision.datasets` and to create a `DataLoader` for it.

```
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

training_set_mnist = datasets.MNIST('./mnist_data', train=True, download=True)
train_loader_mnist = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_set_mnist, batch_size=128,
                                                 shuffle=True)
```

Assume that several Python processes have access to the folder `./mnist_data` and execute the above piece of code simultaneously; in my case, each process is a different machine on a cluster and the data set is stored in an NFS location accessible by everyone. You may also assume that the data is already downloaded in this folder so `download=True` should have no effect. Moreover, each process may use a different seed, as set by `torch.manual_seed()`.

I would like to know whether this scenario is allowed in PyTorch. My main concern is whether the above code can change the data folders or files in `./mnist_data` such that if ran by multiple processes it can potentially lead to unexpected behavior or other issues. Also, given that `shuffle=True` I would expect that if 2 or more processes try to create the `DataLoader` each of them will get a different shuffling of the data assuming that the seeds are different. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, it is ok....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My main concern is whether the above code can change the data folders
> or files in ./mnist_data such that if ran by multiple processes it can
> potentially lead to unexpected behavior or other issues.

You will be fine as processes are only reading data, not modifying in (loading `tensors` with data into RAM in case of `MNIST`). Please notice processes **do not** share memory addresses, hence `tensor` with data will be loaded multiple times (which shouldn't be a big problem in case of `MNIST`).

> Also, given that `shuffle=True` I would expect that if 2 or more
> processes try to create the DataLoader each of them will get a
> different shuffling of the data assuming that the seeds are different.

`shuffle=True` **has nothing to do with data itself**. What it does, is it get `__len__()` of provided `dataset`, makes a range `[0, __len__())` and this range is shuffled and used to index `dataset`'s `__getitem__`. Check out [this section](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#data-loading-order-and-sampler) for more info about `Samplers`.